# Bing Map API : On Right Click open popup and display latitude and longitude

Tags: angular, bing-maps

In my Angular application, when I right click on bing map I want to open small pop up with input textbox, button, label. Also want to display latitude and longitude of that point into the label.

I know how to open the contextMenu on right click but don't know how to open small form with latitude,longitude and button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.

To get lat and long on right click on map,

```
// Add a right click event to the map
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.map, 'rightclick', function (e) {
    const x1 = e.location;
    that.clickedLat = x1.latitude;
    that.clickedLong = x1.longitude;
    jQuery('#myRadiusModal').modal('show');
});
```

I use jQuery modal popup to show small form when right click on map.

Thanks